# PHP save a generated number to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Sorry, I am beginer with code and with english :). I have a code what save some information to database. The database have a "id" and have a "next_number" column. When use the script that update a cell in the next_number column. But I want to update the full column with that number. The "next_numer" is various. I want to save this "$department->next_number + 1" to all "id"s. Somebody can help on me?

```
//...
    public static function generateCode($department_id)
{
    $code = '';
    $db   = JFactory::getDbo();

    $department = RSTicketsProHelper::getDepartment($department_id);

    if ($department->generation_rule == RST_DEPARTMENT_RULE_RANDOM)
    {
        // trick to enter the loop below
        $found = true;
        while ($found)
        {
            // add the department prefix
            $code = $department->prefix . '-2017' . strtoupper(self::generateNumber(4));

            $query = $db->getQuery(true);
            $query->select($db->qn('id'))
                ->from($db->qn('#__rsticketspro_tickets'))
                ->where($db->qn('code') . '=' . $db->q($code));
            $db->setQuery($query);
            $found = $db->loadResult();
        }
    }
    elseif ($department->generation_rule == RST_DEPARTMENT_RULE_SEQUENTIAL)
    {
        // add the department prefix
        $code = '2017' . str_pad($department->next_number, 3, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT) . $department->prefix;

        $department->save(array(
            'id'          => $department->id,
            'next_number' => $department->next_number + 1
        ));
    }

    return $code;
}
```

Comment: $department is a "category". This is an RSTicketPro code.  And when submit a ticket That get a "code" All of department get code from 1. All of deaprtment get a prefix. In here 2017 001 + a department prefix letter. Exaple 2017001A, 2017002A, 2017001B, 2017002B, All of department start form 1. And I want all depatment use one sequence. Like this: 2017001A, 2017002A, 2017003B, 2017004B,...

Comment: For the example way online you can add you code and use some online php render here example : http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ example based on your http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d2f05bbee9de7997078a35af2534530191c5dc1c

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question, but if you want to sum +1 in the column 'next_number' for all the records in your table you can do it easily using SQL. Example:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME SET next_number = next_number + 1;
```

Or if you want only to update one record you can use:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME SET next_number = next_number + 1 WHERE id=1;
```

I hope that help you a little.

Regards.